# SWT: how to remove or cancel mouse down event?

Tags: java, combobox, swt, mouseevent, double-click

I am extending a combo box which does selection on mousedown event, but I want the selection on double-click. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So your combo is opened and you want it to select an entry only of you double-click on it?

Comment: Yes, You are right. i want to select an entry only when i double-click.

Comment: Please edit your question so we can understand it easily. What have you tried so far?